# How to wrap multiple tags under a new tag in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an input xml structure as shown

```
<sometag> <a></a> <b></b> <c> <d></d> </c>  </sometag>
```

Now I need to wrap everything in between `<sometag>...</sometag>` to a new tag which will be a child tag for `sometag`

The desired structure would be

```
<sometag> <newtag> <a></a> <b></b> <c> <d></d> </c> </newtag> </sometag>
```

How can this be achieved?

I am aware I can use wrap and unwrap function twice to achieve the same.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<sometag> <a></a> <b></b> <c> <d></d> </c>  </sometag>",'xml')
soup.sometag.wrap(soup.new_tag('newtag'))
soup.sometag.unwrap()
soup.newtag.wrap(soup.new_tag('sometag'))
print soup
```

But is there any other better method?

Answer (score 1):

As you are only dealing with tag names an option could be renaming `sometag` to `newtag` and then wrapping `newtag` with a new `sometag`:

```
soup.sometag.name = 'newtag'
soup.newtag.wrap(soup.new_tag('sometag'))
```

Or wrapping first and renaming last:

```
soup.sometag.wrap(soup.new_tag('sometag')).sometag.name = 'newtag'
```